# In this derivative why is $t>0$ required?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For $t>0$,
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}t^{-2.25} = -2.25t^{-3.25}$$
We could rewrite it as a denominator of root $4$ with radicand $t^{13}$ so why can it not be $0$?

Comment: Because a negative exponent like in $t^{-2.25}$ can be written $\dfrac{1}{t^{2.25}}$ and value $t=0$ in the denominator is not welcome.

Comment: Yes, I understand it can't be zero but why can it not be negative?

Comment: @O.kth: what is $(-1)^{0.25}$ ?

Comment: If you sketch a graph of that function you may see why evaluating it or its derivative for  $ t \le 0$ is a problem. In order to use formal rules (for differentiation or anything else in mathematics) you should understand where they work and why.

Answer (score 1):

Note that :

$$t^{-3.25} = \frac{1}{t^{3.25}}= \frac{1}{t^{13/4}} = \frac{1}{t^3\cdot t^{1/4}}$$

In order for such an expression to be well defined, the denominator must be non-zero, thus $t \neq 0$. We are also talking about a root, thus $t \geq 0 \; \wedge t \neq 0 \implies t >0$.

**Edit :**

It cannot be negative, since :

$$$$

Comment: Hi, why can t not be negative though?

Comment: @O.kth See my updated answer. $t^{1/4}$ cannot have negative values as arguments !

Comment: sorry but I believe your answer didn't update successfully!

Comment: @O.kth Reload, it is there. The initial expression is broken up to : $$\frac{1}{t^3\cdot t^{1/4}}$$ which cleary cannot have negative arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $t>0$ because of two things. First of all, $t^{-3.25}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{t^{13}}}$ and the function $f(x)=\sqrt[4]{x}$ is defined only for $x\ge0$. Notice that the expression $t^{13}$ yields negative numbers for $t<0$ and you can't take the fourth root of a negative number. Secondly, the value $t=0$ makes the denominator zero and you can't divide by zero in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

$t^{-2.25} = \frac{1}{t^{2.25}}$

But you can't evaluate it at ***t = 0***, because the the function is undefined at *t = 0.*

It tends to infinity at *t = 0*

Answer (score 0):

If $t>0$ then $t^a$ is well-defined for all real $a$.

If $t=0$ then $t^a$ is well-defined for all $a>0$.

If $t<0$ then $t^a$ is well-defined for integer $a$.

In your case, $a = -2.25 = -\frac{9}{4}$ (before differentiation) or $a = -3.25 = -\frac{13}{4}$ (after differentiation). In both cases, $a$ is *not* an integer, so $t^a$ is not well-defined for $t<0$.